# Delete a django model object with blank file field

Tags: python, django

I have a django model that looks like this

```
class Foo(models.Model):
        ...
        article = models.FileField(upload_to='articles', blank=True, default=None, null=True)
        ...
```

when I try to delete an object `bar` of Foo model using `bar.delete()` where any file has not been uploaded in the article field, I get the following error.

```
[Error2] Is a directory
```

How can I delete such objects?

**EDIT**

The code for the deletion looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="delete" value="yes" /> Delete
    <input type="radio" name="delete" value="no" checked="checked" /> Don't Delete
</div>
```

**DJANGO**

```
def del_foo(request,foo_id):
        context_dict = {'msg':'Unable to delete'}
        try:
                bar = models.Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)
                _delete = True if request.POST.get("delete")=="yes" else False
                if _delete:
                        bar.delete()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        except Exception as e: print str(e)
        return render(request, 'edit.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the relevant code for the delete operation, but it sounds like you calling `os.remove(path)`.  Since the filename is blank the path to be removed is being constructed as something like `os.path.join(dir, '')` resulting in just *dir*.  Calling `os.remove(dir)` results in the errro you indicated.   You'll need to avoid this in the delete operation.

```
def delete(self):
    if self.article:
        # delete operation
    # rest of delete, maybe the default parent delete
    super(Foo, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

There are certainly more complicated things you can do but that should point you in a hopefully helpful direction.

Comment: The chane proposed by you to override the delete method doesn't work in my case. I am not using `os.remove(path)` operation, I have made edits to the question for your reference, Please have a look at it.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?  If you run ``os.remove()`` on a directory you will see that it is the exact error that is returned.  The only question is who is doing it on your behalf if you aren't doing it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

in Django 1.9
i created

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Foo(models.Model):
    article = models.FileField(upload_to='articles', blank=True, default=None, null=True)
```

then i created two objects

```
Foo.objects.create(pk=1)
Foo.objects.create(pk=2)
```

then i tried to delete it

```
Foo.objects.get(pk=1).delete()
(1, {u'Foo': 1})
```

its worked like charm!

Comment: Your answer didn't answer OP's question, your example doesn't even involve in anything with `FileField`, not to mention addressing the issue's root cause.